# Type checking on Caché Objects

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems

What is the point of type definition on method parameters on Caché Object (from Intersystems) since after it's pre-compiled to the .int format, it removes any typing information, thus making no difference at all?

Comment: Bit off-topic but you can use "oRef.%ClassName(1)" to confirm/check that the argument is an instance of the class that you actually want.

Answer (score 1):

Those types aren't used/checked internal to Cache code, but they are used when you expose your classes via XML, SQL, etc.

One would hope that in a future version Intersystems would start doing some compile-time type checking, but that may be too much to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing ANSI M code, you shouldn't have types at all.  My guess is that this is specific to Intersystems code.

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't be there because it doesn't make any difference. It's just a fake typing feature like many others fake features.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't really datatypes in Cache, so there is no type checking.